# Creating a struct from mach_timebase_info()

Tags: c, swift

Creating a time base info struct in C is easy, but in Swift the following does not work in the playground:

`let timebaseInfo: mach_timebase_info_data_t = mach_timebase_info(&timebaseInfo)`

The error is `Variable used within its own initial value`

I understand the error, but I am unable to think of a way to do this without dropping down to C.  Is there a Swift only way that I am missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  :-)

Edit: Actually I see "A" problem with the above, the "=" doesn't make sense.  But I did try the following also:

```
let timebaseInfo: mach_timebase_info_data_t
mach_timebase_info(&timebaseInfo)'
```

With an error stating timebasedInfo used before initialization.  :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use `UnsafeMutablePointer<Type>`, as follows:

```
let p = UnsafeMutablePointer<mach_timebase_info_data_t>.alloc(1)
mach_timebase_info(&p.memory)
```

Comment: Yes, that works as well, but don't forget to release the memory when it is no longer needed.

Comment: ... and you can simplify the second line to `mach_timebase_info(p)`.

Comment: You don't need to allocate a buffer on the heap. You can just grab a pointer to the exsting value on the stack: `var result = mach_timebase_info_data_t()`, `mach_timebase_info(&result)`

Comment: Oh yeah, Martin already pointed that out up the page hah

Answer (score 7):

The `mach_timebase_info` function is declared as

```
typealias mach_timebase_info_t = UnsafeMutablePointer<mach_timebase_info>
// ...
func mach_timebase_info(info: mach_timebase_info_t) -> kern_return_t
```

which means that you can pass an (initialized) `mach_timebase_info` variable
as an "in-out expression" with `&`:

```
var timebaseInfo = mach_timebase_info(numer: 0, denom: 0)
let status = mach_timebase_info(&timebaseInfo)
if status == KERN_SUCCESS {
    // ...
}
```

For more information, see [Interacting with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html) in the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" manual:

> **Mutable Pointers**
>
> When a function is declared as taking an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Type>`
>   argument, it can accept any of the following:
>
> - `nil`, which is passed as a null pointer
> - An `UnsafeMutablePointer<Type>` value
> - An in-out expression whose operand is a stored lvalue of type `Type`,
>     which is passed as the address of the lvalue
> - An in-out `[Type]` value, which is passed as a pointer to the start of
>     the array, and lifetime-extended for the duration of the call

Comment: Thank you both very much for the great answers!

Answer (score 1):

swift 5.5:

```
let timebaseInfo: mach_timebase_info_data_t = {
    let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<mach_timebase_info_data_t>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    precondition(mach_timebase_info(pointer) == KERN_SUCCESS)
    let info = pointer.pointee
    defer { pointer.deallocate() }
    return info
}()

func convertToNanoseconds(_ value: UInt64) -> UInt64 {
    return  (value * UInt64(timebaseInfo.numer)) / UInt64(timebaseInfo.denom)
}
```