# High-precision timer in iOS

Tags: ios, time

What is the most precise way to measure time intervals in iOS?  So far I have been using `NSDate` to "mark" events and then `timeIntervalSinceDate` method to calculate the interval, but is there more precise approach?  E.g. Windows has so called [QPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx) for that kind of thing.  Is there something similar in iOS (or MacOSX) world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get down to nanoseconds using `mach_absolute_time()`. Here is an article on using it:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1398/_index.html

It also exists on iOS.

Comment: Wow, that was fast.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: And for anyone interested how that could work in Swift here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591179/creating-a-struct-from-mach-timebase-info